# Why were 4-byte integers chosen as the best way of storing individual trits within IOTA software?

Tags: iri-node, legacy-protocol, ternary, economics, scalability

update: Since this was posted, on Jun 11, an issue was opened by one of the IOTA Foundation developers to look into how to make the storage of trits use less memory. Although moving to a `byte[]` is not ideal, it at least tries to solve a future memory use problem in IoT devices.

See [Reduce the memory footprint by a factor of 4 using byte array](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/issues/799)

---

In the IOTA IRI software and related projects, the three ternary values (-1,0,+1) are individually mapped into 4-byte integer containers, i.e. 4 bytes are used to store individual trits in memory.

Furthermore, in many places in the IRI code, both a binary representation exists in `byte[]` containers (no loss of economy) and a trinary representation exists in `int[]` containers (4 bytes per trit entry).

### Trit-to-byte conversion within the IRI software

There is a 20X loss of radix economy due to the fact that transactions and hashes have hard-coded container sizes and use 4 bytes for every trit.

To store a number between `-128 <= x <= 127` requires one byte. In the IRI software, the same number range requires between 1 and 5 trits. That is between 4 bytes for 1 trit to 20 bytes for 5 trits. In the IRI, each trit array requires 20 times as much memory as just storing it in binary form.

Among alternatives, each byte could be used to represent 5 trits numerically, and 4 trits graphically - if two bits are used to represent each trit.

See **Alternatives** further down for an example of a visual packing and a sample function to **sum a pack of 4 trits** and **negate a pack of 4 trits**.

### Example Class in the IRI that holds Trits

The ubiquitous [Hash.java](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/model/Hash.java) class within the IRI software stores identical data as binary in `byte[49]` byte internal arrays and trinary in `int[243]` integer internal arrays (972 cum. bytes) -- often simultaneously storing the data as both trinary and binary.

Within [Hash.java](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/iota/iri/model/Hash.java), one of the binary or trinary arrays is lazily initialized depending on whether the object was instantiated with binary or trinary data. This is all moot due to the fact that as soon as `hashcode()` or `equals()` or `compare()` is called, the binary data is produced and kept alongside.

The trit content is initialized as soon as any hash comparisons or cyrptographic security are used on the hash, or the hash is used alongside Transaction objects. What this means is that the lazy initialization has no net benefit to memory consumption and it further adds to complexity within the code.

### Other examples

#### Transaction

A `Transaction` contains 8019 trits. The number of bytes used to contain this with the current scheme is 32KB. In binary, this would only require approximately 1.6KB.

When `Transaction.java` is used, the data is stored simultaneously as bytes (in the class) and trits in the `TransactionViewModel.java` that accompanies every transaction. Additionally, every TransactionViewModel stores an additional `Hash` object that also contains yet more 4-byte int arrays.

This limits the number of transactions that can be cached in RAM memory. Furthermore, with the churning of the many embedded `Hash` objects in Transactions, the Java Virtual Machine also needs to perform additional garbage collection.

#### Node

In `Node.java`, where 15,000 `Hash` objects are stored (16MB of trinary data), it is also stored as binary data within the `Hash` objects. If this was just binary data or a different trit-to-byte mapping was used, the node could store up to 20 times as many objects in a RAM cache than it currently does. That would **increase the cache size from 15,000 to somewhere below 300,000 with little to no effect on memory consumption and possibly a great effect on performance in a high throughput server node environment.**

#### TipsViewModel

In the `TipsViewModel.java`, there are 5000 tips stored in each of the `tips` and `solidTips`. Online network statistics show that the full nodes are often filling this container to the maximum allowed entries. Each of the tips are Hash objects and have data simultaneously stored as `byte[]` and `int[]`. Without the duplicate storage in binary and trinary, the number of tips that could be cached would be up to 20X as many as currently allowed.

With binary only data or a different trit-byte mapping scheme, up to 100,000 of each `tips` and `solidTips` could be cached in ram, greatly increasing on-the-fly software analytics and even spam and attack prevention within the node.

#### SignedFiles

In `SignedFiles.java`, the snapshot is verified by reading a tryte stream, converting the characters to String trytes in `Converter.asciiToTrytes`, then converting again to trits (4 bytes per trit) in `Converter.trits`, then passing the data to `Kerl.java` where it is now converted to bytes in 2 separate stages `bytesFromBigInt(bigIntFromTrits(trit_state))` and then operated on by Keccak (binary) hash function. Afterwards, the data from Keccak is converted to a `BigInteger` where it is then re-converted back into trits with `tritsFromBigInt(bigIntFromBytes(byte_state))` and then subsequently used in the curl digest.

If the data was exclusively binary, the most time-consuming and laborious function of trytes-to-trinary-to-BigInteger-to-bytes would be eliminated by a straightforward passing of the data to Kerl for Keccak digesting.

#### UDPReceiver

In `UDPReceiver.java`, incoming transactions via the Gossip protocol, are received, passed to `Node.java`, where a `TransactionViewModel` is created that stores both the binary data `TransactionViewModel(final byte[] bytes, Hash hash)` and where the received `Hash` object is now also containing verified trits (4-byte ints) via the `Hash calculate(bytes,tritsLength,curl)` function in `Hash.java`. As such, the data is stored as binary data (as received) and also stored in trits with 20x radix loss ... and then cached in all the internal caching structures for future reference.

#### Milestone

In `Milestone.java`, the process of verifying milestones involves reading data persisted to disk and comparing it. Data is read into `Hash` objects in `TransactionViewModels` and then compared according to byte data (all `Hash` objects compare only on byte data) and then compared to trit data which involves also now marshalling the data to a 4-byte trit format with a loss of radix. This process would possibly be faster, more efficient, or less error-prone if only binary data were used.

### Looking at other IOTA libraries such as the [iota.lib.js](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js) library

#### [asciiTotrytes.js](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js/blob/develop/lib/utils/asciiToTrytes.js)

All Javascript Strings are 2-byte encoded (16 bits per character). That means that everywhere a tryte is used in the javascript libraries, two bytes are used for every 3 trits.

#### [converter.js](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js/blob/develop/lib/crypto/converter/converter.js)

As can be seen, trits are converted to integer arrays in the javascript identically to the Java version in the IRI.

### What I am not referring to

This question regards the IRI software at https://github.com/iotaledger/iri as written and stated as:

> The main IOTA Reference Implementation and the embodiment of the IOTA network specification.

I am not talking about or referring to how objects are persisted to disk/SSD such as in the `PersistenceProvider.java`. The database stores 7 types of objects: Transaction, Milestone, StateDiff, Address, Approvee, Bundle and Tag. All of those objects are collections of `Hash.java` objects and when they are written to disk, they are all marshalled to pure binary form with no loss of storage efficiency.

What I am talking about, and what matters to this question, is what happens internally in the program, in structures, in caches and collections and functions.

### Alternatives

#### Pack 4 trits to a byte using two bits to represent each trit

For a visual and highly storage-space efficient solution, two bits could have been used to represent [0,1,2] or [-1,0,1] (balanced), resulting in 4 trits packed to each `byte` and 20 trits packed to each `int`:

```
 10 = -1
 00 =  0
 01 =  1

 01_00_01_10 = [1,0,1,-1]
 10_00_10_00 = [-1,0,-1,0]
 etc.
```

Calculating the sum is also quick and easy because an AND and/or bitwise shift can isolate any trit within the number:

```
   01_00_01_10
 & 00_00_00_11
 = 00_00_00_10 = 10 (isolates first trit)

   01_00_01_10
 & 00_00_11_00
   >>> 2
 = 00_00_00_01 = 01 (isolates second trit)

   01_00_01_10
 & 00_11_00_00
   >>> 4
 = 00_00_00_00 = 00 (isolates third trit)

   01_00_01_10
   >>> 6
 = 00_00_00_01 = 01 (isolates fourth trit)
```

Calculating the sum is also easy with a lookup or with powers of three.

This is one of a few schemes outlined in [**The Ternary Manifesto**](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~jones/ternary/index.shtml), by Douglas W. Jones at THE UNIVERSITY OF IOWA Department of Computer Science (c) 2012.

#### A Function to quickly sum a pack of 4 trits

A function could quickly convert this to binary. Using the above scheme, 4 trits can be added up with the following, highly machine-optimizable, function:

```
int tritsToValue(final byte n) {
    return (n & 1) - ((n >>> 1) & 1)
        + ((n >>> 2) & 1) * 3 + ((n >>> 3) & 1) * -3
        + ((n >>> 4) & 1) * 9 + ((n >>> 5) & 1) * -9
        + ((n >>> 6) & 1) * 27 + ((n >>> 7) & 1) * -27;
}
```

This is much faster than the current IOTA scheme of loading 4 `int` values, converting them using powers of three, and then summing them.

#### A Function to quickly negate a pack of 4 trits

```
byte negate(final byte n) {
    return (byte) ((n & 0b10_10_10_10) >> 1 | ((n & 0b01_01_01_01) << 1));
 }
```

### Rationale

If a different trit-to-byte mapping was used, there would be less memory consumption. Furthermore, the performance and flexibility of working with trit values would be greatly enhanced.

The code in some places could be much more highly performant if the size of the collections was increased or if additional optimizations were performed once the code was made strictly binary - or used a packed trit system.

Of course, all of the issues and examples mentioned above could be done in binary only with greater efficiency, less memory consumption, less complicated code and a leaner cleaner code-base.

Furthermore, all of the marshalling with various types of converting (ascii, trytes, trits, bytes) and all of the composite methods to perform those functions, offer areas of vulnerability and hidden bugs and exploits.

With that in mind ...

**What is the reason that this mapping schema was chosen in the IRI software foundation?**

**What are the advantages to using this mapping?**

**What are the implications of this for memory management, processing speed and ease of use by developers?**

Comment: It's premature optimisation, probably. IOTA doesn't run on processor/memory constrained devices for many reasons, and reducing the memory consumption won't enable it to do so.

Comment: Good analysis. Still sad to see that there is no good answer on this. Says a lot about IOTA, to be frankly.

Comment: Keep it civil guys. If anyone has an objective disagreement with the question this should be detailed objectively in a comment when aiming to better the question or otherwise in an answer. SE does not advertise or condone discrediting anyone because you don't like their opinion.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about the legacy-network and it is a good idea to keep only Shimmer/ShimmerEVM and latest IOTA Chrysalis questions

Answer (score 2):

I was in discord around the time this was originally posted. I figured someone would have provided the answer right after we discussed it...

@Come-from-Beyond brought it up himself, and he said that it was a good write-up, and question, but he was concerned that the answer was too simple.

Java (the language it was first implemented in) uses 4 bytes for an integer.

Abra soon.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more about that discussion? Or a history link?